# Meteor not updating window variable

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a simple Meteor app and am trying to set a window variable,

```
User = {}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  User = Meteor.user();

}
```

but when I go to the console it is "undefined".

Comment: You're sure it's `undefined` and not `null`?

Comment: Are you actually logged in? Have you added the `accounts-base` package to your app? You definitely need to clarify your question by adding more context because there are just so many places where the thing might have gone wrong.

Comment: In the browser console: `Meteor.user() = Object {_id: "MPTqJZJmyb7DTFaAW", profile: Object, services: Object}`  `User = undefined`

Comment: I have `accounts-base` added.  I'm just trying to figure out why the User variable is not being reactively set.

Comment: The only explanation I can find is that you somewhere else have an assignment to `User` whose expression evaluates to `undefined`. If you want your assignment to be reactive, you need to write it inside a function and pass it to `Tracker.autorun`. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just to be sure, you only typed `User` in the console, right? `User = undefined` should evaluate to `undefined`.

Comment: Your `User` variable is not reactive. So it won't update whenever `Meteor.user()` changes. I'd just use `Meteor.user()` whenever you need the user. That way you are only using one reactive variable instead of two.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I was trying to run a login server on a subdomain (login.domain.com) in an iFrame and then set a window variable `User` that would be accessible to the parent (open to advice on whether this makes sense as a strategy).  It looks like User was undefined because `Meteor.User` is not available, even when I wrap it in a `Meteor.startup` function.  I did find a package (`differential:event-hooks`) that has a callback for when `Meteor.User` is set, but would `Tracker.autorun` be a better way to do this?